# Git commit wants to delete files. How do I un-mark them for deletion?

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using Netbeans8.2 IDE for java and am working on a small personal project. I use git to handle version control and push to github. For some reason, half of my files got marked for deletion in git and if I commit, they will be removed. I dont know how to un-mark them for deletion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NetBeans, that would be:

```
Team -> Git-> Revert/Recover-> Reset..
```

See "[3.2.7 How to Reset](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/version_control.htm#sthref149)": chose the "mixed" mode, which overwrite all changes in Index and leave changes in Working Tree.

You will need to add again the files you actually wanted part of the commit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any skills on netbeans, but you can to open your local repository in bash and type:

`git reset path_file_to_unstaged`

When you add files, they wait on stage status to commit.

Try understand [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) here.